# How do I get this to log every iteration?

Tags: javascript

```
function annoyingSong(start){
 for (let i = start; i >= 0; i--) {
  sol = `${i} bottles of soda on the wall, ${i} bottles of soda, take one down pass it around ${i-1} 
  bottles of soda on the wall` 
  return sol;
 }
}

console.log(annoyingSong(20))
```

This only logs sol on the first iteration. How do I get it to return or log every iteration?

Comment: Hint: What happens when you abruptly `return` in the middle of a function?

Comment: Hint: `annoyingSong(start, fn)` and then `fn(\`${i} bottles...\`)`.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh the return is inside my loop!

Comment: `return` is like pulling the ripcord on your parachute. Don't do it until the right time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation.

```
function annoyingSong(start, fn) {
    for (let i = start; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(fn(i));
    }
}

function fn(count) {
    return `${count} bottles of soda on the wall, ${count} bottles of soda, take one down pass it around ${count - 1} bottles of soda on the wall`;
}

annoyingSong(20, fn);
```

Comment: if you have any question, please email me wizard.work@pm.me